# Getting the name of a python script that is importing your module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

So I want to make myself a module that at some point needs the name of the python script that is importing my module, like argparse does to make the help argument.

ex.

```
python script.py -h

     USAGE: script.py [-h] [-arg1] [-arg2] . . .
```

How does argparse acces the name of the script that is importing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the "main" script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the built-in `__file__` to retrieve the name of the file being run. If you need just the filename and not the path, use os.basename() to strip the path.

Comment: Seems like he asked for the path of the file importing the file in question. That doesn't necessarily have to be the file currently being run.

Comment: it doesn't give the name of the script that is importing the name both __file__ and os.path.basename(__file__) give , basically, the name/ path of the module